# Do digraphs with "other" symmetries have interesting properties

Tags: symmetry, directed-graphs

**Question:**
do digraphs $G(V,A)$, whose adjacency matrix exhibits certain symmetries, have mathematically interesting properties?
The most famous such symmetry is $(i,j)\in A\iff(j,i)\in A$ for which certain hard problems become easy cf e.g. [Computing Cycle Covers without Short Cycles](https://virt.dacs.utwente.nl/%7Emantheyb/conferences/ESA2001_BlaeserSiebert_CycleCovers.pdf), but what about
$(i,j)\in A\iff (n-i,\,j)\in A$
$(i,j)\in A\iff (i,\,n-j)\in A$
$(i,j)\in A\iff (n-i,\,n-j)\in A$
$(i,j)\in A\iff (n-j,\,n-i)\in A$,
for $n=2k$ one could also take the antisymmetries
$(i,j)\in A\iff (j,i)\not\in A$
$(i,j)\in A\iff (n-i,\,j)\not\in A$
$(i,j)\in A\iff (i,\,n-j)\not\in A$
$(i,j)\in A\iff (n-i,\,n-j)\not\in A$
$(i,j)\in A\iff (n-j,\,n-i)\not\in A$
into consideration.
do the (anti-)symmetries imply specific properties that are invariant under permutation of vertex indices?
By specific properties I mean properties that digraphs for which no adjacency matrix with the respective (anti-)symmetry exists, do *not* have that property.